# Ag-grid not display nested json

Tags: cell, ag-grid

I have json. I want render it to ag-grid. All fields work correctly, but i cannot render `possible_positions` items. What i make wrong?

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "surname": "Иванов",
    "stop_sheet_status_id": 1,
    "status_treatment": {
      "id": 1,
      "display_name": "active",
      "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:19.043Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:19.043Z"
    },
    "nationality": {
      "id": 1,
      "display_name": "nationality",
      "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:16.441Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:16.441Z"
    },
    "possible_positions": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "display_name": "programmer",
        "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:17.883Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:17.883Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "display_name": "engineer",
        "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:17.964Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:17.964Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "display_name": "worker",
        "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:18.053Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:18.053Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**example.js**

```
 {
       headerName: "treatment date", field: "treatment_date",
       width: 100, pinned: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "nat display ", field: "nationality.display_name",
      width: 180, pinned: true
    },
    {
      headerName: "position", field: 
      "possible_positions[0].display_name",
      width: 180, pinned: true
    }...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define a [value getter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0) for that column. The default method for getting a value assumes that the data is only in nested objects, not arrays. Which is why `nationality.display_name` works for the column `nat display`.

This is how you can define a valueGetter

```
{
  headerName: "position", 
  valueGetter: params => params.data.possible_positions[0].display_name,
  width: 180, pinned: true
}
```

Actually, looking into the source code, you ***might*** be able to get away with this:

```
{
  headerName: "position", field: 
  "possible_positions.0.display_name",
  width: 180, pinned: true
}
```

Since the source splits the provided field name on `.`, then digs through the objects recursively using bracket notation.